# What's wrong with this query?

Tags: sql, mysql, mysql-error-1064

using MySQL version 4.0.27:

```
UPDATE `t` SET `col_x` = 
(SELECT `col_x` FROM `t` WHERE `col_y`='123456') WHERE `col_y`= '456789'
```

> Error message: #1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax.  Check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'SELECT `t` FROM `b` WHERE `col_x`='1234

I tried `LIKE '%123456%'`

Comment: what's the full error message?

Answer (score 3):

I'm sorry to disappoint you, but subqueries are not supported in your version if MySQL.

Subqueries have been introduced in ver 4.1 according to [MySQL Dev Zone](http://dev.mysql.com/tech-resources/articles/subqueries_part_1.html)

Comment: I had this idea, however I found subquery documentation in MySQL 3.23/4.0/4.1 Manual, so I thought my version belongs to it too :(
thanks

Answer (score 1):

You can't select and update from the same table in a query.

reference: [mysql update documentation](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/update.html)

Answer (score -1):

Check out [this page](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/4.1/en/identifiers.html).  Apparently you need to set your SQL mode to 'ANSI QUOTES'